# Logging from a groovlet

Tags: groovy, jetty, groovlet

Is there a way to write into the server log from a groovlet script? I've tried the following to no avail:

- Create a class with `@Log4j` annotation within the groovlet (`@Log4j` works fine in the rest of the project)

```
@Log4j('LOGGER')
class Log {
    static Logger getLogger() {
        LOGGER
    }
}
```

- Use `ServerContext` instance implicit variable `application`:

```
application.log('Hello world')
```

Any ideas welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs didn't appear using the first method because of `Log4j` filtering on `log4j.properties`.

I created a separate class `GroovletLogger` inside one of our unfiltered packages and I can log fine from groovlets.